# proxy_ignore_client_abort on doesn't work in nginx for gRPC

Tags: nginx, grpc

I use nginx for gRPC for loadbalance. I found some 499 code in nginx access log.
and the error log says "client prematurely closed connection while processing HTTP/2 connection"

```
2022/03/19 14:27:40 [debug] 40#40: worker cycle
2022/03/19 14:27:40 [debug] 40#40: epoll timer: 27280
2022/03/19 14:27:40 [debug] 40#40: epoll: fd:17 ev:2001 d:00007FEDD5A92C01
2022/03/19 14:27:40 [debug] 40#40: *30305 http2 read handler
2022/03/19 14:27:40 [debug] 40#40: *30305 SSL_read: 0
2022/03/19 14:27:40 [debug] 40#40: *30305 SSL_get_error: 5
2022/03/19 14:27:40 [debug] 40#40: *30305 peer shutdown SSL cleanly
2022/03/19 14:27:40 [info] 40#40: *30305 client prematurely closed connection while processing HTTP/2 connection, client: 113.116.31.189, server: 0.0.0.0:9081
2022/03/19 14:27:40 [debug] 40#40: *30305 http run request: "/config.Config/DelayTest?"
2022/03/19 14:27:40 [debug] 40#40: *30305 http upstream check client, write event:0, "/config.Config/DelayTest"
2022/03/19 14:27:40 [debug] 40#40: *30305 finalize http upstream request: 499
2022/03/19 14:27:40 [debug] 40#40: *30305 finalize grpc request
2022/03/19 14:27:40 [debug] 40#40: *30305 free keepalive peer
2022/03/19 14:27:40 [debug] 40#40: *30305 free rr peer 1 0
2022/03/19 14:27:40 [debug] 40#40: *30305 close http upstream connection: 18
2022/03/19 14:27:40 [debug] 40#40: *30305 run cleanup: 00007FEDD68C1A30
2022/03/19 14:27:40 [debug] 40#40: *30305 free: 00007FEDD68C19E0, unused: 24
2022/03/19 14:27:40 [debug] 40#40: *30305 free: 00007FEDD686D640, unused: 64
2022/03/19 14:27:40 [debug] 40#40: *30305 event timer del: 18: 17750575983
2022/03/19 14:27:40 [debug] 40#40: *30305 reusable connection: 0
2022/03/19 14:27:40 [debug] 40#40: *30305 http finalize request: 499, "/config.Config/DelayTest?" a:1, c:1
2022/03/19 14:27:40 [debug] 40#40: *30305 http terminate request count:1
2022/03/19 14:27:40 [debug] 40#40: *30305 http terminate cleanup count:1 blk:0
2022/03/19 14:27:40 [debug] 40#40: *30305 http posted request: "/config.Config/DelayTest?"
2022/03/19 14:27:40 [debug] 40#40: *30305 http terminate handler count:1
2022/03/19 14:27:40 [debug] 40#40: *30305 http request count:1 blk:0
2022/03/19 14:27:40 [debug] 40#40: *30305 http2 close stream 1, queued 0, processing 1, pushing 0
```

But when i set proxy_ignore_client_abort on to the nginx, it doesn't work. nginx still return 499.
my server config is as below

```
charset UTF-8;
server_tokens off;

error_log /usr/local/kong/logs/proxy-error.log ${LOG_LEVEL};


underscores_in_headers on;
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;

# injected nginx_http_* directives
client_body_buffer_size 64k;
client_max_body_size 32m;
http2_recv_buffer_size 64k;
log_format main '${LOG_MAIN}';
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_session_tickets on;
ssl_session_timeout 1d;
tcp_nodelay on;


server {
    server_name http-svc;
    listen 8080;
    location /nginx_status {
        stub_status;
        access_log off;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
    }
    location /health {
        return 200 "healthy\n";
    }
}
server {
    server_name meemo;
    listen 0.0.0.0:9081 ssl http2;
    error_page 500 502 503 504  /error_handler;

    access_log /usr/local/kong/logs/proxy-access.log main;
    error_log  /usr/local/kong/logs/proxy-error.log ${LOG_LEVEL};

    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/server.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/server.key;
    ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
    
    # injected nginx_proxy_* directives
    grpc_buffer_size 64k;
    proxy_buffer_size 64k;
    proxy_buffers 4 64k;
    proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
    real_ip_header X-Real-IP;
    real_ip_recursive off;
    grpc_connect_timeout 30s;
    grpc_read_timeout 30s;
    grpc_send_timeout 30s;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_socket_keepalive on;
    location = /error_handler {
        internal;
        default_type application/grpc;
        add_header grpc-status 14;
        add_header grpc-message "unavailable";
        return 204;
    }
    location / {
        grpc_pass grpc://grpc_servers;
        grpc_set_header Content-Type application/grpc;
        grpc_socket_keepalive on;
        
        grpc_set_header     Connection "";
        grpc_set_header      X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        grpc_pass_header     Server;
        grpc_pass_header     Date;
    }
}
upstream grpc_servers {
    server  ${GRPC_PROXY};
    keepalive_timeout 65s;
    keepalive 1000;
    keepalive_requests 1000;
}
```

so if proxy_ignore_client_abort doesn't support in nginx ?
or if there are any solution for this problem?